# Generating a tarball of Linux modules?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am working on an embedded Linux distribution and currently I have to share the Kernel and its Kernel modules with my team. Normally I'd use Yocto/Openembedded framework, but right now I'm can only use the Linux Makefile. Is there a way to generate a tarball of the Kernel modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly but you can do it manually.

First compile the kernel and the modules normally. Then install to a temporary directory:

```
$ make INSTALL_MOD_PATH=$(pwd)/myroot modules_install
```

And then build the tar file:

```
$ tar -cf modules.tar -C myroot .
```

And clean the temporary directory (for the next build to be clean):

```
$ rm -r myroot
```

Then, in the target machine, install it with:

```
# cd /
# tar -xf modules.tar
# depmod -e
```

Comment: Great answer. I was hoping for a `make` option, but this works really well.

Answer (score 2):

Just found this question and thought I'd still give an answer.
According to [the make help documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/makehelp.txt), you can just run a

```
make tarbz2-pkg
```

It includes everything from the make install command, including the kernel, config, symbols and modules.

Comment: Very handy indeed, even though I posted my question nearly 5 years ago! Ty.